# Searching through XML within an HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'll try to explain it as short as possible. I have an iframe tag which contains an XML database. Above it there's a textfield and a button on which I'd like to add a function that gets the value from the textfield and displays only the results that match the entered query for a specific XML tag.

How would I go about doing this? I'm aware of how to get the value, but the part where I have to actually display only the matched results is something I have no idea how to do.

If anyone cares, it's a college project, they just want to see we know some JavaScript basics. Here's the page where I'd like to see the mentioned above happen:

http://poorlymadelolfansite.co.nf/browse.html

Answer (score 1):

In your iframe you have an XML with a processing instruction telling the browser to apply an XSLT stylesheet which transforms the XML to HTML with a table. Thus if you were to access the iframe's document with Javascript you would not find XML elements but rather the result HTML document of the XSLT transformation.

Based on that I think you have two options:

1. You can keep the XSLT unchanged and script the HTML document in the iframe to hide the table rows that should not be shown.
2. You adapt the XSLT to add one parameter or two for the values to filter by and then you need to use the APIs exposed by the browser to apply the XSLT with the parameters set and you need to replace the contents of the iframe with the new transformation result.

None of the both approaches would do "searching through XML ... using JavaScript" as in the first option you would search through HTML and in the second XSLT would search through the XML, as before.

As for accessing the iframe's document through Javascript, use

```
var iframeDoc = window.frames.dsoChamps.document;
```

Then access the table with

```
var table = iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

then you can search through the `table.rows` collection to check whether `table.rows[i].cells[j].textContent` has the value you want. You can hide a row by setting `table.rows[i].style.display = 'none';`, to show it again you can simply set `table.rows[i].style.display = '';`. As an alternative you might simply define a CSS class and set the `className` of the rows you want to hide and unset it to show the rows again.

One caveat is that `textContent` is only supported in recent IE versions, for older ones you need to check `innerText`.

For the alternative to apply the XSLT with Javascript, inside Mozilla, Opera, Safari, Chrome you have the same API https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations, with all IE versions you however need to use a different API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

As for the XSLT, I would at least change it to have the table created with a `thead` for the header row, that is a cleaner document structure and simplifies your task to search through the rows as then you could search `table.tBodies[0].rows` and would ignore the header row.